# Trying to create a count variable in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to create a counter variable in R which loops through the n rows of my 442 column dataframe and increases the counter by 1 on every 55th row.

I've tried the following code:

```
dataset$num=ceiling(row(dataset)/55)
```

which works fine, however R duplicates the function for *every* column in my dataframe rather than simply creating a single new column containing the counter variable. So I have 442 copies of the same variable titled num.1, num.2, ..., num.442.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want something like:

```
rep(1:1000,each=55,length.out=nrow(dataset))
```

The 1000 here could be anything as long as it's larger than `nrow(dataset)/55`.